# MySqli query to multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to convert the results from a MySQLi select to a multidimensional array but am not getting the desired result. This is the data returned from the SELECT statement:

```
+----+------------+
| id | value      |
+----+------------+
| 2  | Red        |
| 2  | Blue       |
| 1  | Green      |
| 1  | Yellow     |
| 1  | Orange     |
| 3  | Teal       |
+----+------------+
```

There can be multiple values with the same id. My fetch statement looks like this:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $colors[] = array($value);
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Red
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Blue
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Green
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Yellow
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Orange
    )
    [5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Teal
    )
)
```

However, want I really want is the array to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Red
        [1] => Blue
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Green
        [1] => Yellow
        [2] => Orange
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Teal
    )
)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please, provide full select query. And fix your while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use the id to group them inside the loop. Example:

```
$stmt->bind_result($id, $value);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $colors[$id][] = $value;
}

// $colors = array_values($colors); // optional, if you want to reindex the keys
```